# ServiceStack Ws-Security Auth Provider

Tags: servicestack, ws-security

I'm trying to figure out how to support ws-security as authentication mechanism in SS.

My goal is to have all DTO handled in json,xml,saop11,saop12(that part has been achieved following the [SS documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support)) and supporting multiple auth providers including one based on ws-security.
DTOs should not be affected at all by the authentication mechanism.

In case the DTO will be sent using saop12, the soap message will be the the call sample generated by the metadata endpoint(soap envelope + soap body) plus a soap header including the ws-security element for the WS-Security Username Authentication. A dedidcated "soap auth provider" should inspect the message, use the soap header -> security element and perform the authentication.

Along with the soap auth provider, I may have other built-in auth mechanism that may used for json message and/or other formats.

Exists a SS auth provider based on ws-security that I'm not aware of?

Any guidelines, suggestions, thoughts to implement it?

At the present than my solution

//AppHost

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomAuthUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(), 
        new SoapMessageAuthProvider(),
    }
));

// required by the SoapMessageAuthProvider to inspect the message body serching for ws-security element
PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes) =>
{
    httpReq.UseBufferedStream = false;
});
```

I based the SoapMessageAuthProvider on the built-in BasicAuthProvider.
Since the SoapMessageAuthProvider requires to inspect the incoming message on each call serching for ws-security element, I implemented IAuthWithRequest

```
public void PreAuthenticate(IRequest req, IResponse res)
{
    //Need to run SessionFeature filter since its not executed before this attribute (Priority -100)            
    SessionFeature.AddSessionIdToRequestFilter(req, res, null);

    var userPass = ExtractSoapMessageUserNameCredentials(req);//req.GetBasicAuthUserAndPassword();
    if (userPass != null)
    {
        var authService = req.TryResolve<AuthenticateService>();                
        //var response = authService.Post(new Authenticate
        //{
        //  provider = Name,
        //  UserName = userPass.Value.Key,
        //  Password = userPass.Value.Value
        //});

        authService.Request = req;
        var session = authService.GetSession(false);
        var userName = userPass.Value.Key;

        //Add here your custom auth logic (database calls etc)
        var userAuth = new UserAuth();
        userAuth.Id = 10;
        userAuth.UserName = userName;


        var holdSessionId = session.Id;
        session.PopulateWith(userAuth); //overwrites session.Id
        session.Id = holdSessionId;
        session.IsAuthenticated = true;
        session.UserAuthId = userAuth.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        session.UserAuthName = userName;
    }
}

//called by CustomAuthUserSession.IsAuthorized
// to be reviewed to keep isolated from other providers
public override bool IsAuthorized(IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Authenticate request = null)
{
    if (request != null)
    {
        if (!LoginMatchesSession(session, request.UserName))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return !session.UserAuthId.IsNullOrEmpty();//filled by PreAuthenticate
}
```

the custom session calls each provider, including the SoapMessageAuthProvider that meanwhile, through the PreAuthenticate method, filled out the session with authenticated user data.

```
public class CustomAuthUserSession : AuthUserSession
{
    public override bool IsAuthorized(string provider)
    {
        var tokens = ProviderOAuthAccess.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Provider == provider);
        return AuthenticateService.GetAuthProvider(provider).IsAuthorizedSafe(this, tokens);
    }
    ...
}
```

I need to make sure the soap provider will be always invoked for soap message w/ ws-security and the call should not be authenticated by other providers:
- user get authentication through the CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(cookie based)
- user call the service supply json message within the web request that carries the auth cookie
- a further call sends a soap message carrying the same auth cookie: since the message is in soap format and includs the soap header ws-security, the call should be authenticated only using the soap provider using the soap header ws-security within the message.

I understand that a weird scenario, but I'm trying to understand how to accomplish it.

My guess that happends through the [ServiceStack.AuthenticateAttribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/b41e750d3a9d2be409620940e5b6e39c168d02f0/src/ServiceStack/AuthenticateAttribute.cs) line 72

```
matchingOAuthConfigs.OfType<IAuthWithRequest>()
    .Each(x => x.PreAuthenticate(req, res));
```